# Swap related memory problem in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, swapfile

When I run a `top` and get it to show swap usage, I get the following output. However, I have disabled swap with `swapoff -a` prior to starting firefox. What is shown in the `SWAP` field here then? 
When I do `cat /proc/meminfo`, I get a nonzero value for a field named `SwapCached`. What is this? My guess it this is the aggregate of all the `SWAP` values shown in `top`. How are these related to total memory used by a process?

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  SWAP 
    COMMAND                                                                                                                                      
         1604 dumrat    20   0  287m  62m  26m R    1  3.1   0:05.03 225m firefox-bin                                                                                                                                  
         1415 dumrat     9 -11 94264 4668 3552 S    0  0.2   0:00.10  87m pulseaudio
```

Answer (score 1):

My *best guess* id this.

When you say `swapoff`, it prevents tasks from further 'swapping' (techically, it's paging, not swapping), but does not remove already swapped pages from swap devices. Often various shared libraries go to swap right at the moment of loading: they are here to stay for long time, no point wasting time swapping them when the load is high. These libraries are in RAM as long as they are needed by active processes, but *also* in swap space.

Maybe Firefox uses some of these librsries that are already mapped to swap space — Xlib, GTK, etc, and this swap space is counter to its 'SWAP' column. Linux tends to count all shared pages to each process that shares them, RAM or not.

Again, this is my guess; take with a grain of salt.

Comment: I turned swap off, wrote to `/etc/fstab` and rebooted and tried. Same result.